# How to send any QUERY_STRING to my index.php by htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to send all adress url which the user type in my domain as

QUERY_STRING to root directory to file index.php

with parameter url=QUERY_STRING

example if the user type `www.mydomain.com/abc/123`

it will be `www.mydomain.com/index.php/?url=abc/123`

my htaccess code don't send the parameter url I don't know why:

```
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

my php file:

```
<?php

    if ($GET['url']){
        $url = $GET['url'];
        echo ($url.'<br />');
    }
?>
we are in root directory.
```

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding the `[NE]` flag to your RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L,NE]
```

This will ensure that your question mark is not escaped.

I'm a little confused by your RewriteCond condition. The regular expression should match any possible string, including an empty string, so the condition should always pass.

Answer (score 0):

It's in `$_SERVER`: `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

Comment: my problem is when the user type QUERY_STRING the htaccess not send the QUERY_STRING to index.php you can see it here  [http://kidslearning4fun.com/](http://kidslearning4fun.com/)

Comment: Never mind my answer, reading troelskn's answer, I realise I misunderstood the question. Sorry ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you *need* to make it a query string parameter? Otherwise just redirect he request to index.php and use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` from within php, which will contain the original requested path.

Here's a `.htaccess` rule that will work for that:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -d
RewriteRule  ^.*$  -  [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f
RewriteRule  ^.*$  -  [L]

RewriteRule ^.*$    index.php [L]
```

Comment: yes this is the correct code but I want the QUERY_STRING even if it is not file or directory in all case I want the QUERY_STRING

Answer (score 0):

```
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$    index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It will works..